# Convert date to current month date

Tags: php, date

I need to convert any date to a date within 1 month from today. Dates that are smaller than today should be converted to next month.

For example, current day is 2018-09-11 and dates are:

```
$dates = ['2018-08-01', '2018-09-11', '2018-09-15', '2018-10-15', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-31'];
```

Results should be as follows, respectively:

```
$result = ['2018-10-01', '2018-09-11', '2018-09-15', '2018-09-15', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-01, '2018-09-30'];
```

Edit: I have tried so far using strtotime('+1 month') but it fails on dates such as 2018-10-31 since it'll give 2018-12-01. It also fails on using strtotime('-1 month') on dates such as 2018-10-31 where it gives 2018-10-01 instead of 2018-09-30.

My current solution is following, but I believe it can be done MUCH simpler somehow:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2018-10-31');
if (date('d', $timestamp) > date('t')) {
    $date = date('Y-m-t');
} elseif(date('d', $timestamp) < date('d')) {
    $year = date('Y');
    $month = date('m') == 12 ? 1 : (intval(date('n')) + 1);
    if ($month < 10) {
        $month = '0'.$month;
    }
    $day = date('d', $timestamp);
    $date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
} else {
    $date = date('Y-m') . '-' . date('d', $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: and can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [ask] a good question and [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RamRaider  I just did.

Comment: Your result array is flawed, In Sep are 30 days, in your results you have `2018-09-31`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I just corrected it. I was quickly creating an input/output to describe the idea, so made a mistake.

Comment: Ahh, but there is no easy way to convert that, it's easy to say I want this `2019-01-31` to be this `2018-09-30` but the logic to do that is more complex then one would think. The normal date time stuff will give you `2018-10-01` so the logic has to know to minus a day or two when that happens, it's not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix What I want to convert it to is relative to the current date. If today was 2018-12-31, I would like to convert all dates in a range of 2018-12-31 up to 2019-01-30. The code I have provided above is what gives me that, but I was hoping there was an easier way to do it as I don't think someone else will be able to understand what this piece of code works.

Comment: no there is not an easier way, you could use DateTime object, etc.  But the logic will not differ much.  There is no relative way to get the last day of the month without knowing you are the last day of the month.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
if('2018-09-11'<date("Y-m-d"))
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", '2018-09-11'));
```

for example

Comment: This doesn't check if the date is in the past, the number of days in the month, or deal with leap years.

Comment: updated. you can replace the '2018-09-11' with a variable

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Using date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month", '2018-10-31')) will give you date 2018-12-01. That's why I can't realy on using +- 1 month

Comment: @Viktor what do you mean please?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I expect to get 2018-11-30 (last day of the month) instead of the 2018-12-01 from date 2018-10-31.